# How to make Executable Package of Mininet Python Script?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, mininet, nuitka

**How to make Executable Package of Mininet Python Script?**

I have mininet custom topology python script which I have the requirement to make executable in Linux to work where mininet is not installed.

### I made it executable in ubuntu-Pyinstaller. **It works fine where mininet is installed** but not working in other machines where mininet is not installed. On running the executable file it gives below error:

```
   pradeepkumar@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tp4$ sudo python tp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tp.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mininet.net import Mininet
ImportError: No module named mininet.net

pradeepkumar@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tp4$ cd dist/

pradeepkumar@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tp4/dist$ ls
tp

pradeepkumar@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tp4/dist$ sudo ./tp
*** Test Network Script 
*** Creating nodes
Cannot find required executable mnexec.
Please make sure that Mininet is installed and available in your $PATH:
(/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tp.py", line 124, in <module>
  File "tp.py", line 23, in TP
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 85, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 657, in checkSetup
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 665, in setup
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/moduledeps.py", line 68, in pathCheck
NameError: global name 'exit' is not defined
[3874] Failed to execute script tp
pradeepkumar@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tp4/dist$
```

---

Used NUITKA:

Same issue, and exactly same error message as above.

Note: I used to make tar.gz of the package before I move it to another machine and then untar there.

I tried all commands in their user manuals to make executable but not working on 2nd machine...

[nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html](http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html)

### Below is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python



from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Node
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.log import  setLogLevel, info
from threading import Timer
from mininet.util import quietRun
from time import sleep
from mininet.cli import CLI




def TP(cname='controller', cargs='-v ptcp:'):

    "Create network using Open vSwitch and ODL Controller in Mininet."


    info( "*** Creating nodes\n" )
    controller = Node( 'c0', inNamespace=False )
    s1 = Node( 's1', inNamespace=False )
    s2 = Node( 's2', inNamespace=False )
    h1 = Node( 'h1' )
    h2 = Node( 'h2' )


    info( "*** Creating links\n" )
    TCLink( h1, s1 )
    TCLink( s1, s2 )
    TCLink( s2, h2 )


    info( "*** Configuring Hosts\n" )

    h1.setIP( '192.168.100.1/24' )
    h2.setIP( '192.168.100.2/24' )



    info( "*** Starting network using Open vSwitch\n" )

    s1.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl del-br dp0' )
    s1.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl add-br dp0' )
    s2.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl del-br dp1' )
    s2.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl add-br dp1' )

    controller.cmd( cname + ' ' + cargs + '&' )          

    for intf in s1.intfs.values():

        print intf

        print s1.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl add-port dp0 %s' % intf )



    for intf in s2.intfs.values():

        print intf

        print s2.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl add-port dp1 %s' % intf )



    # Note: controller is ODL 


    s1.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl set-controller dp0 tcp:127.0.0.1:6633' )

    s2.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl set-controller dp0 tcp:127.0.0.1:6633' )



    info( '*** Waiting for switches to connect with controller' )

    while 'is_connected' not in quietRun( 'ovs-vsctl show' ):

        sleep( 1 )

        info( '.' )

    info( '\n' )


    info( "*** Running test\n" )
    h1.cmdPrint( 'ping -c 10 ' + h2.IP() )

    info( "*** Running iperf test Between h1 and h2\n" )
    print "iperf: h1--s1--s2--h2"

    h2.cmd('iperf -s &')
    h1.cmdPrint('iperf -c 192.168.100.2 -t 10')


    info( "*** Stopping network\n" )

    controller.cmd( 'kill %' + cname )

    s1.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl del-br dp0' )

    s1.deleteIntfs()

    s2.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl del-br dp1' )

    s2.deleteIntfs()

    info( '\n' )



if __name__ == '__main__':

    global net

    setLogLevel( 'info' )

    info( '*** Test Network Script \n' )

    Mininet.init()

    TP()
```

---

Please advise that how can I make this ***mininet-python script executable package*** in Linux to work on other machines where mininet is not installed?

Thanks

Comment: can you please post the commands, that you used to create the executable?

Comment: Hi gelonida
thanks for the prompt reply.

I used below command:

`sudo /home/pradeepkumar/.local/bin/pyinstaller --onefile tp.py`

Comment: what do you get if you don't use `sudo` both in running the script and running it with `python` command? also post the output of this command: `which python`

Comment: Hi Reza
Please find the output below:

`ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~/Desktop/tp[17:38]$ python tp.py`

`*** Test Network Script `

`*** Mininet must run as root.`
`ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~/Desktop/tp[17:38]$ python --version
Python 2.7.6`
`ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~/Desktop/tp[17:38]$ ./dist/tp
Traceback (most recent call last):`
 ` File "tp.py", line 5, in <module>`
   ` from mininet.net import Mininet`
`ImportError: No module named mininet.net`
`[18576] Failed to execute script tp`
`ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~/Desktop/tp[17:39]$ `

Comment: I just used NUITKA to make executable: I can run successfully nuitka processed executable file on the same machine where mininet is installed but when I moved this executable package to another ubuntu machine then It says " Please make sure that mininet is installed". Problem is not solved yet. It should not ask for mininet of 2nd machine, should keep all required files in the package. I tried all commands in their user manuals to make executable but not working on 2nd machine...
https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html